# Over write last N characters of string in python

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to find a smart way to pad a variable length string.

I grab the length of a text chunk, set up my fixed length string and index it like so:

```
    text = 'string'
    pad_seq_len = 10
    text_len = len(text)
    padded_text = '_'*pad_seq_len
    print(padded_text)
    padded_text[(pad_seq_len-text_len):pad_seq_len]
    print(padded_text)
```

Output:

```
'__________'
'_____string'
```

Is there a shorter way to do this using negative indexing?  I could try:

```
    padded_text[-1:-pad_seq_len]
```

but I was wondering if there was an even better way...

Comment: What's wrong about `'_' * (pad_seq_len - len(text)) + text`?

Comment: Check out [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust).

Comment: I think you want `'{0:_>{1}}'.format(text,pad_seq_len)`

Comment: Try `(padded_text+text)[-pad_seq_len:]`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think that's the simplest way to do it.